# Concatenate 2 files with different files extension

Tags: python, yaml, markdown, python-re, listdir

```
apple.yml
apple.md
orange.yml
orange.md
```

I have files as .md and .yml I would like to concat them into one .md file if the filename match

What would be the next step here?

```
contents = {}
file_extension1 = "yml"
file_extension2 = "md"

# Get all files and directories that are in current working directory
for file_name in os.listdir('folder/'):
#     print(file_name)

    # Use '.' so it doesn't match directories
    if file_name.endswith(('.' + file_extension1 , '.'+ file_extension2)):
        print(file_name)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can use the `glob` module:

```
from glob import glob

for f1 in glob("*.yml"): # For every yml file in the current folder
    for f2 in glob("*.md"): # For every md file in the current folder
        if f1.rsplit('.')[0] == f2.rsplit('.')[0]: # If the names match
            with open(f1, 'r') as r1, open(f2, 'r') as r2: # Open each file in read mode
                with open(f"{new}_f2", 'w') as w: # Create a new md file
                    w.write(r1.read()) # Write the contents of the yml file into it
                    w.write('\n') # Add a newline
                    w.write(r2.read()) # Write the contents of the md file into it
```

---

---

---

That code is for when there are inconsistent `yml` and `md` files. If all the `yml` files have a corresponding `md` file, and they are in a folder with other interfering `yml` and `md` files, you can:

```
from glob import glob

m = sorted(glob("*.md"))
y = sorted(glob("*.yml"))

for f1, f2 in zip(m, y):
    with open(f1, 'r') as r1, open(f2, 'r') as r2:
        with open(f"new_{f1}", 'w') as w:
            w.write(f1.read())
            w.write('\n')
            w.write(f2.read())
```

---

---

UPDATE:

To address the comment below:

```
from os import listdir

files = listdir()
for f in files: # For every yml file in the current folder
    if f.endswith('.yml') and f.rsplit('.')[1]+'.md' in files:
        with open(f1, 'r') as r1, open(f.rsplit('.')[1]+'.md', 'r') as r2: # Open each file in read mode
            with open(f"{new}_f2", 'w') as w: # Create a new md file
                w.write(r1.read()) # Write the contents of the yml file into it
                w.write('\n') # Add a newline
                w.write(r2.read()) # Write the contents of the md file into it
```

Comment: You don't need to glob both patterns.  For each *.yml file, you can just check directly if the corresponding *.md file exists.

Comment: since you are online can you explain me how to move the new {new}_f2 to a new folder

Comment: Change `with open(f"{new}_f2", 'w') as w:` to `with open(f"C:/Users/User/Desktop/Folder/{new}_f2", 'w') as w:`. `'C:/Users/User/Desktop/Folder/'` is the folder path.